# Incorrect datetime value mysql57

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

After updating my mysql version from 5.6  to 5.7  I get an error :

```
Incorect datetime value: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 for column 'create_time' at row 1
```

And this is the structure for create_time

```
`create_time` DATETIME DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you are running a current MySQL 5.7 version newer than version 5.7.7, or disable strict mode. [Versions 5.7.4 to 5.7.7 incorporated `NO_ZERO_DATE` SQL mode into strict mode.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-changes)

> As of MySQL 5.7.4, the `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO`, `NO_ZERO_DATE`, and `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` SQL modes are deprecated. From MySQL 5.7.4 though 5.7.7, these modes do nothing when named explicitly. Instead, their effects are included in the effects of strict SQL mode (`STRICT_ALL_TABLES` or `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`). **In other words, strict mode means the same thing in those versions as the pre-5.7.4 meaning of strict mode plus `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO`, `NO_ZERO_DATE`, and `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`.**
>
> The MySQL 5.7.4 change to make strict mode more strict by including `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO`, `NO_ZERO_DATE`, and `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` caused some problems. For example, in MySQL 5.6 with strict mode but not `NO_ZERO_DATE` enabled, `TIMESTAMP` columns can be defined with `DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`. **In MySQL 5.7.4 with the same mode settings, strict mode includes the effect of `NO_ZERO_DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` columns cannot be defined with `DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.** This causes replication of `CREATE TABLE` statements from 5.6 to 5.7.4 to fail if they contain such `TIMESTAMP` columns.

Comment: OK, i understand now. :D thanks. But what i can do to slove. I need to use ZERO_DATE.  Can this ZERO_DATE be enabled in 5.7 ?

Comment: If i change with NULL   , should be fine?

Comment: Disable strict mode if you need to. Whether it will work with `NULL` depends entirely on your application logic.